# How can I put discord.py events to another file?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need to log many events on my Discord server and i am trying add logging feature to my bot. But it looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(m):
    created_at = m.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    log_content = f'{m.author} deleted message.\n[{created_at}] "{m.content}"'
    await Logging().write_log(1, log_content)

@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(m_before, m_after):
    created_at = m_after.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    edited_at = m_after.edited_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    log_content = f'{m_after.author} edited message.\n[{created_at}] "{m_before.content}"\n[{edited_at}] "{m_after.content}"'
    await Logging().write_log(1, log_content)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    created_at = message.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    log_content = f'{payload.member} addded reaction {payload.emoji} to message from {message.author}.\n[{created_at}] "{message.content}"'
    await Logging().write_log(2, log_content)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    created_at = message.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    log_content = f'{payload.member} removed reaction {payload.emoji} from message by {message.author}.\n[{created_at}] "{message.content}"'
    await Logging().write_log(2, log_content)

# and more
```

How can I put this to another file? Or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is dpy's [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs#cogs)

> There comes a point in your bot’s development when you want to organize a collection of commands, listeners, and some state into one class. Cogs allow you to do just that.

A quick example here would be :

```py
class Logging(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        # Do your logging stuff here
        ...
```

More details on adding and removing Cogs have been detailed in the documentation which you can [read here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)

NOTE: In some versions of dpy `add_cog`, `setup` are coroutine functions and needs to be `await`ed. Be sure to crosscheck your version :D